# Marking incoming calls and text messages

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to mark each time an incoming call or a text message arrives while using my app. This is for documentation purposes, since my app deals with car safety.

Any way to keep track of this ? I only need to know when a call / text came in, not any additional data.

Comment: You can check the new CoreTelephony Framework there is a call back for seeing when a call is being made. But I think your app should be active...

Answer (score 1):

Yes This Method in your AppDelegate gets called when there is such an interruption

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can     occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS     message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background     state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES     frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}
```